# Swiftで現在時刻から少しずらしたローカル通知がうまくいかない

Tags: swift

### 現在時刻から少しずらしたローカル通知がうまくいかない

Swiftで現在時刻から`１０秒`時間をずらして通知を表示したい際に`trigger`のDateComponentsの`seconds`をいじってやりたいと思っていますが、通知が表示されません。triggerが`nil`である即時通知はうまくいきます。

### 動かないコード

```swift
let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
notificationContent.title = "お知らせ"
notificationContent.body  = "通知内容"
notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

let date = Date()
var dateComponent = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: date)
dateComponent.second! = 10 // 現在時刻から10秒ずらす

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponent, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notification", content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

### 動くコード(即時通知)

triggerをnilにして即時通知は動作してくれます。

```swift
let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
notificationContent.title = "お知らせ"
notificationContent.body  = "通知内容"
notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notification", content: notificationContent, trigger: nil)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現在の`dateComponent`を作るコード:

```
let date = Date()
var dateComponent = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: date)
dateComponent.second! = 10 // 現在時刻から10秒ずらす
```

には、2点ほど大きな問題点があります。

- `dateComponent.second! = 10`は「現在時刻から10秒ずらす」のではなく、「現在時刻の秒だけを10に書き換える」ものです

  例えば現在時刻の秒が20の時にこの処理で作られた`dateComponent`は過去の時刻を表すことになり、決してマッチすることはありません。
- `dateComponents(in:from:)`で作成される`DateComponents`には、「時刻がマッチしたかどうか」の判定に必要以上の情報が含まれる

  `print(dateComponent)`としてやると、`calendar: gregorian (current) timeZone: Asia/Tokyo (current) era: 1 year: 2021 month: 4 day: 12 hour: 23 minute: 9 second: 17 nanosecond: 925995945 weekday: 2 weekdayOrdinal: 2 quarter: 0 weekOfMonth: 3 weekOfYear: 15 yearForWeekOfYear: 2021 isLeapMonth: false`のような感じになります。一番まずいのは`nanosecond`まで含まれている点だと思われますが、条件が厳しくなりすぎて、やはりマッチすることはまずあり得ない状態になります。

---

「現在時刻から10秒後」を表す`DateComponents`が欲しければ、例えばこんな風にします。

```
        let date = Date()
        let dateComponent = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date + 10) //<- 現在時刻から10秒後
        print(dateComponent) //-> year: 2021 month: 4 day: 12 hour: 23 minute: 25 second: 14 isLeapMonth: false
```

---

実際に「現在時刻から１０秒時間をずらして通知を表示したい」場合には、

```
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10, repeats: false)
```

のように`UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`を使うべきところでしょうが、今回は`UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`を使う練習ということでしょうか。

Comment: 意図を汲んでくださり、ありがとうございます。無事うまくいきました。`[.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]`のところが長くなってしまうのが、気になるのですが、いい感じにできるのはないですかね？

Comment: @zunda さん、私の知る限りでは無いです。長いと言っても何十行にもなるわけじゃないですから、そのまま受け入れるか、自前でextensionを書くなどするしかないでしょう。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。